# Is this verse of mahabharata found in the BORI critical edition of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, identification-request, arjuna, critical-edition

Did this verse make the cut for the critical edition?

> उभौ मध्वासवक्षिप्तावुभौ चन्दनरूषितौ । स्रग्विनौ वरवस्त्रौ तौ
>   दिव्याभरणभूषितौ ॥
>    (I saw) both of them (Krishna and Arjuna) drunk with
>   Madhvâsava (sweet spirituous liquor made from honey), both adorned
>   with sandal paste, garlanded, and wearing costly garments and
>   beautiful ornaments.” (Mahabharata - Udyoga, LVIII. 5)

Comment: Is there any reason for reverting the title? The Qn from the longer horizon perspective is very broad. However the specific glimpse of verse (as I edited before) is easy to search & refer. There is no insult to lord Krishna or Arjuna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is present in Udyoga Parva chapter 58 as mentioned in the question. The BORI Critical edition is available on Sanskrit.org in [Devanagari](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-05.pdf) and in [ITRANS](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh05.itx) transliteration.

Follwing is in ITRANS transliteration scheme

> ubhau madhvAsavakShIbAvubhau chandanarUShitau |
>     sragviNau varavastrau tau divyAbharaNabhUShitau || 5||

Comment: i have gone through the sanskrit one but there is a downloadable vol.1 how much parva do it contain do you have it?

Comment: @Fiercelord It is present in the Udyoga Parva. I didn't download it. I searched online.

Comment: Ok there is an english file of 12 mb i never downloaded it so i was thinking that may be you have that ok i get that we both see critical edition online.

Comment: Where are the exact verses ? Who will going to explore whole scripture . Give links to exact verses.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Link to exact verse is not present. I gave you location of the verses. It is easy to search who knows the internet. Just click on the chapter 58 in Devanagari link and it takes you to chapter 58.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The translation of the verse is present in [Bibek Debroy's tr. of Mahābhārata](https://www.amazon.in/Mahabharata-4-Bibek-Debroy/dp/014342517X/) based on the critical edition.

> **The Mahabharata: Volume 4**
>
> **Introduction**
>
> ...
>
> Familiarity with Sanskrit is dying out. The first decades of the twenty-first century are quite unlike the first decades of the twentieth. Lamentation over what is inevitable serves no purpose. English is increasingly becoming the global language, courtesy colonies (North America, South Asia, East Asia, Australia, New Zealand, Africa) rather than the former colonizer. If familiarity with the corpus is not to die out, it needs to be accessible in English.
>
> There are many different versions or recensions of the Mahabharata. However, between 1919 and 1966, **the Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute (BORI) in Pune produced what has come to be known as the critical edition.** This is an authenticated text produced by a board of scholars and seeks to eliminate later interpolations, unifying the text across the various regional versions. **This is the text followed in this translation.** One should also mention that the critical edition's text is not invariably smooth. Sometimes, the transition from one shloka to another is abrupt, because the intervening shloka has been weeded out. With the intervening shloka included, a non-critical version of the text sometimes makes better sense. On a few occasions, I have had the temerity to point this out in the notes which I have included in my translation. On a slightly different note, the quality of the text in something like Dana Dharma Parva is clearly inferior. It couldn't have been 'composed' by the same person.
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> **Section Fifty-Three**
>
> **Yana-Sandhi Parva**
>
> Chapter 721 (58)
>
> Dhritarashtra asked, "What did those two great-souled ones, Vasudeva and 
>   Arjuna, say? O immensely wise one! Tell me. I wish to listen to your words."
>
> Sanjaya said, "O king! O descendant of the Bharata lineage! Listen to me and I 
>   will tell you how I found Krishna and Dhananjaya and what those two brave ones 
>   said. O king! After purifying myself, I entered the quarters of those gods among 
>   men, looking at my toes and joining my hands in salutation. Abhimanyu and the 
>   twins are not allowed entry into the abode where the two Krishnas, and 
>   Krishna<sup>127</sup> and the beautiful Satyabhama, reside. **Both of them were drunk with liquor and both had their bodies smeared with sandalwood. They wore garlands, excellent garments and were adorned with divine ornaments.** The two destroyers of enemies were seated on a large and golden couch, which was covered with many carpets. I saw that Keshava's feet were on Arjuna's lap, while the great-souled Arjuna's were on Krishna and Satya.<sup>128</sup>
>
> ...
>
> <sup>127</sup> Krishnaa, Droupadi.
>   <sup>128</sup> Satyabhama.

Comment: Beer (Alcohol content: 4%-6% ABV generally) and Wine (Alcohol content: 9%-16% ABV) are alcoholic beverages produced by fermentation.
Beer is generally composed of malted barley and/or wheat and wine is made using fermented grapes.
The above two have low alcohol content. So, while being alcoholic drinks they aren't included in the general definition of 'Liquor'.                                                 Madhvasava is a wine of low intoxicating products.

Comment: Please pass on your comments to [Bibek Debroy](https://twitter.com/bibekdebroy). @Anubhav

Comment: I'm just correcting that liquor and wine are different things according to Wikipedia.